# keypress, keydown, keyup value of input box AFTER event

Tags: jquery, events

```
$("#last_4_cc").keyup(function()
{
    $.post('<?php echo site_url("sales/set_last_4_cc");?>', {last_4_cc: $('#last_4_cc').val()});    
});
```

When doing keypress() or keydown() I get the value before the key is inputed, when I do key up, I get the val() for the after the key is inputed.

Example:

Cur Value:
333

keyPress "3"
Cur Val 333

Cur Value:
333

keyUp "3"
Cur Val 3333

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior? KeyPress and KeyDown events are supposed to be triggered before the default action is performed, KeyUp fires afterwards.

See here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html