# How do I check and change the value of an input with using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If user types in a value more than 5, I want to set it to 5.

```js
function maxValCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('xxx').value > 5) {
    document.getElementById('xxx').value = 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="xxx" type="number" onkeypress="maxValCheck()" max="5" min="1" value="1" />
```

Comment: change event to onkeyup

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have provided? What errors are you getting? What isn't happening that should? What is happening that shouldn't?

Comment: `function maxValCheck(fld) {
  if (fld.value > 5) {
    fld.value = 5;
  }
}` works too and is a better event if you pass the field: `oninput="maxValCheck(this)"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911047/keydown-event-new-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change event to `onkeyup`:

```
<input id="xxx" type="number" onkeyup="maxValCheck()" max="5" min="1" value="1"/>
```

Comment: You just suggested what?

Comment: oninput is a better event

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element by getElementById or from the querySelector and need to specify the event that you're going to trigger as the first parameter and second parameter is the function that you're going to execute on the added method in addEventListener.

```
<input id="xxx" type="number" max="5" min="1" value="1" />

<script>
    const selectElement = document.querySelector('#xxx');
    selectElement.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
        console.log("value is changing in input");
    });

    // or

    document.getElementById("xxx").addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
        console.log("value is changing in input");
    });
</script>
```