# How to restrict invalid values from entering in an input field having a regex pattern

Tags: html, typescript

I have an input field in which I want first 4 characters to be numbers only, after that only dot(.) is allowed, and then only 2 numbers allowed. Example: 9999.99

I also want that if I am entering something else it should not enter in input field.

For this I created a regex as : `^[0-9]{4}+\.+[0-9]{2}+$`

HTML: `<input type="text" (keypress)="onKeydown($event)">`

TS:

```
regex = '/^[0-9]{4}+\.+[0-9]{2}+$/';

  onKeydown(event) {
    if(event.target.value.match(this.regex)) {
      return true;
    } else return false;
  }
```

But I guess I am doing something quite wrong here. Kindly let me know about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't *forcibly* prevent the user from typing something. It leads to confusion. Instead, let them type what they want, and let validation catch any errors.

Comment: Yes I think that's the best practice, but unfortunately I had this as one of my client's requirement.

Comment: I would say that part of your job is to advise your client about what is good and what isn't. In this case, it's a very serious usability concern, and poor usability may lead to poor performance, which in turn means loss of sales.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `+` (select 1 or more matches) in your regex.

Instead, you need `|` (or) to catch two cases: when input does not contain dot and when dot is added.

Try something like this: `/^(?:\d{0,4}|\d{4}\.\d{0,2})$/`.

I've added `?:` (non-capturing group mark) to exclude group in match, but it's not necessary.

**UPDATE**: here's a quick sketch using `oninput` event handler:

```js
var regex = /^(?:\d{0,4}|\d{4}\.\d{0,2})$/;
var lastValue = "";

function onInput(e) {
 var currentValue = e.target.value;

 if (!currentValue.match(regex))
  e.target.value = lastValue;
 else
  lastValue = currentValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="onInput(event)">
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex. But I guess there is some issue in my function also. It is letting 5 numbers to be added and then stops.

Comment: That's because you are checking against "current" value, not the "next" value. You'd need to take current value, then add input to it and check if result matches the regex.

Comment: Can you please tell me how the function will be written? Was not able to understand you properly. Thanks.

Comment: Please look on an accepted answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911047/keydown-event-new-value.